# Is that a correct use of "will have been"?

Tags: tense

given that little text:

"by last monday's begining people who time traveled to the past knew that by the end of that same day there will have been a fire"

is "there will have been a fire" applicable?? if so I would like to make an inherent question

would "there would have been a fire" also applicable??

Comment: It's a very strange sentence (and we don't speak of _last Monday's beginning_), but you certainly need _would have been_, not _will have been_.

Comment: You need to read up on your Douglas Adams - https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/369785-one-of-the-major-problems-encountered-in-time-travel-is

Comment: @Kate Bunting, thanks for you attention. Please keep in mind that if the people traveled back to the past at monday start, these people will live throughout this day again that the monday end will be a future to them agree?

Comment: You are talking about events in the past (_last Monday morning_ or _early last Monday_ - note the capital M). Even though Monday evening is in the future to the time-travellers, it is still in the past to the reader. _They knew that there would be a fire that day_ or _there would have been a fire by the end of the day_.

Answer (score 1):

A basic assumption of grammatical tense is that time proceeds in the same way for everyone.  My future is your future. My past is your past.  Grammar doesn't try to deal with time travel.

So there is no answer to your question.  We don't have grammatical structures in English to deal with an event that is in both the past and the future, on different timelines.